# Best practice for persisting User State in special kind of Asp.Net Mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I will try to explain my situation and what I wanted to do. There is not any difficult and rare situation, but I can't find any relative questions or articles in internet.

I have created a web application on **ASP.NET MVC 5**. Users are not going to enter my application directly. Users will enter let's say to `CentralInformationSystem.com`. Then they must login to this website one of supported ways. After signing in, they will see a list of applications. There will be applications which has been allowed to use for the signed user. One of this applications will be my application which has developed in `Asp.Net MVC`.

And the main point is that our applications will not be opened in other tabs or in current tab and so on. Our application will be opened in a big iframe inside the current tab.

And other main point is our applications and `CentralInformationSystem.com` belong to other domains.

The other question of course is, how then I can now *which user has signed in*? And the answer is, `CentralInformationSystem.com` sends encrypted data with the query string to our web site. For example, the URL will look like that:

> MyMvcApplication/Home/Index?Token=jkndid758adsai==qwdbqwiudhqwadoqidwqq=wqdiqw

Also keep in mind that they will always sent different tokens.

And after that, I will decrypt token and find to which user it belongs. Also keep in mind that, one Token can be used only once.

***1. What type of application is my application?***

User will enter very big form. It can actually take almost 3-4 hours. So, I have tried some-type of wizard logic. After entering some portion of datas, I will insert them to the database, get identifier from the database and store it somewhere and take the user to the next level and so on.

***2. What I want to achieve?***

I want to create such logic that, some identifier variables values must be stored in such place that **never must be expired** till the user closes browser or signing out. I don't want to increase session timeout to 5-6 hours.

***3. What if user opens my application in more than one tab?***

Alongside 2 I have also one problem, that user can open my website inside iframe more than one tab. I know that, in `Asp.net` we can differ session per each tab. But, I don't want to store datas in session, because user can stop filling forms after 20 minutes or 4 hours. Also, I cannot use cookie, because cookies will be same for all tabs.

My other option is, to inject hidden inputs with encrypted  value to all views. But, I can't find how to automatically add these datas to each views. Also, it doesn't seem to me as most efficient way.

The other logic is to prevent user to open same application in more than one tab with differen tokens. But, don't how to achieve this also.

***Additional:***

I have read almost all articles and questions/answers. I know how to make it work. But, I want the best approach. Neither of my approaches are efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your own concept of a persistent session that is identified by a hidden input on the page and does not expire, or at least does not expire for a very long time. Have all of your controllers derive from a single base controller and use the OnActionExecuted to add the session "key" to the ViewBag when the result is a ViewResult (you won't need it for partial views or JSON, etc). Every page can then access the ViewBag and create the hidden input - probably you want to use a partial view for this and simply include the partial on every page. Store the data associated with this session in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me write what I have understood from your words. As I got, I must store `Token` query string value in all views as a hidden field with the help of overriding `OnActionExecuted ` method. And to store this data in one of the tables. Then I will update this table with other datas while the user working on application. And I will store some of these datas in session also, but when the session will be timeout I will get these datas back from the database. Then, I can write a job which will delete all rows from this table which has inserted two days ago.
Am I right?

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thanks very much. But I have a very little concern about some points of this approach. I will be very glad if you clear this concern. Is this approach nice overall? My boss is a little bit exacting about such things. İs it bad approach to save such datas in database and then just remove after two days?

Comment: If you don't want to store them in the session, they need to be persisted somewhere.  You could potentially use an in-memory store, but then you run the risk of having the data go away if the apppool is recycled.  I wouldn't have a problem storing it in the database and using some mechanism to clean it out regularly - maybe on app start up if you don't want to create and maintain a separate task. Of course, if it's sensitive information you'll need to take the same precautions as with any sensitive data that you store permanently.